# In Django are these query's equivalent?

Tags: django, optimization

I have to optimise my query's as they take 4 mins each, and i want to do this but i don't know if its valid, fitting_list was a list of querysets, but now it's just one

Going to:

```
company_list.append(Company.objects.filter(uuid__in=fitting_list.manufacturer.company.uuid).distinct())
address_list.append(Address.objects.filter(company__in=fitting_list.manufacturer.company.uuid).distinct())
customer_list.append(Customer.objects.filter(company__in=fitting_list.manufacturer.company.uuid).distinct())
manufacturer_list.append(Manufacturer.objects.filter(uuid__in=fitting.manufacturer.uuid).distinct())
```

From:

```
for fitting_queryset in fitting_list:
    for fitting in fitting_queryset:
        company_list.append(Company.objects.filter(uuid=fitting.manufacturer.company.uuid).distinct())
        address_list.append(Address.objects.filter(company=fitting.manufacturer.company.uuid).distinct())
        customer_list.append(Customer.objects.filter(company=fitting.manufacturer.company.uuid).distinct())
        manufacturer_list.append(Manufacturer.objects.filter(uuid=fitting.manufacturer.uuid).distinct())
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the code ?

Comment: it's hard to explain, but basically it gets the dependencies for a fitting to be inserted into the database. so stuff that a fitting links to

Comment: How are you fetching fitting_list. My suggestion would be, since you are interested only in the company.uuid here, just get them as a list at once. It will reduce the number of database queries. Also, extrace fitting.manuifacturer.company.uuid into a local variable. That way, it would be 1 query, and value would be reused.

Comment: This is probably over simplified example and i'm using the whole queryset in a serialisation function. Simple answer is "doing __in like that doesn't work"